# Getting an error when using an array from a js file

Tags: javascript, html

I have this html file in which I want to display an ordered list.the list comes from an array which is in a js file  and every time I use "src" to connect the two documents I keep getting an error saying the arrays in the js file have been declared which they have not been.
HTML code

```
<div id=fruit>
      <h3>Displaying Fruits</h3>

      <script src="js/list.js">

         var list = document.createElement('ol');
         fruits.forEach(function (element){
           var li = document.createElement('li');
           li.textContent = element;
           list.appendChild(li);
         });
         var fruit = document.querySelector('#fruit');
         fruit.appendChild(list);
      </script>
    </div>
```

JS code

```
const fruits = ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Pineapples', 'Mangos'];
```

error

> **Uncaught SyntaxError**: Identifier 'fruits' has already been declared at VM13 list.js:1

Comment: can you include `list.js` - also you should load up your `list.js` as a script and then have a separate script tag for your html javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See, any script tag which has a `src` attribute, ignores all the content written inside the script block. So, you might need to add one more script tag:

```html
<script src="js/list.js"></script>
<script>
  var list = document.createElement('ol');
  fruits.forEach(function(element) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = element;
    list.appendChild(li);
  });
  var fruit = document.querySelector('#fruit');
  fruit.appendChild(list);
</script>
```

Comment: thank you it worked but the error is still there. it still says fruits has been declared

Comment: at first look it seems that you have multiple fruits declarations in your js file.

Comment: I have looked at the js file and theres only one but its ok, I will ask my teacher thank you for your help.